# EF Core. Get data from many-many relationship

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm new to EF Core. I have many-many relationship between 2 tables. In total, I have these 3 tables:

1. Tenant.
2. UserTenant.
3. User.

User has property "email". I want to get all tenants that are related to user by given user email. How to do that?
I would do something like this but I think is bad approach.

```
var user = await dbContext.Users.FirstAsync(u => u.Email == userEmail);
var userTenants = dbContext.UserTenants.Where(u => u.UserId == user.Id);
etc...
```

Comment: Looks real good.  Not sure why you do not like.

Comment: @jdweng Is it possible to write this in one line? I don't like my approach because between each line I should probably check for nulls, right?

Comment: Why write in one line?  The compiler optimizer will produce same code.  If Id is a primary key than the value cannot be null and then there is no need to check for null.  Your code is very understandable. as is.  Combining code into one line can make it harder to understand.

Comment: @jdweng Okay, thanks. Now I'm trying to understand how to query related tenants. `var tenants = dbContext.Tenants.Where(t => userTenants.Where(u => u.TenantId == t.Id));` this gives error: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'UserTenant' to 'bool'.

Comment: Should be : bContext.Tenants.SelectMany(t => userTenants.Where(u => u.TenantId == t.Id)).ToList();  You may have a tenant with same id that rents more than one location.  You may want anther query that does a GroupBy id.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to create a Class ex:

```
   public class UserEmailViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email{ get; set; }

}
```

and Then

```
var userEmail = await dbContext.SqlQuery<UserEmailViewModel>("select Id, Email from User U , Tenant T , UserTenant UT where u.id=ut.Userid and t.Id=UT.TenantId ")
```

Note That you should add Properties to UserEmailViewModel if you want to add column to the query